# When does a unique_ptr returned by a function (via std::move) go out of scope

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, unique-ptr

I am working with a large object that is stored in a shared memory region, and is returned by a getter. I was running into issues where returning the object by-value was blowing the stack due to the size of the object. To avoid this, I decided to return a `unique_ptr` to a copy of the object on the heap, which I want the calling function to be able to use as a local variable. See my example code below:

*Note: The codebase I am working on is C++11, not C++14, so I cannot use std::make_unique*

```
#include <memory>
struct AbsoluteUnit {
    char bigChungus[10000000];
    int bigChungusSize;
};
AbsoluteUnit g_absUnit;

std::unique_ptr<AbsoluteUnit> getAbsoluteUnit() {
    return std::move(std::unique_ptr<AbsoluteUnit>(new AbsoluteUnit(g_absUnit)));
}

void Example1()
{
    std::unique_ptr<AbsoluteUnit> absUnitPtr = getAbsoluteUnit();
    AbsoluteUnit& absUnit = *absUnitPtr.get();
    ///
    /// Some other code
    ///
}

void Example2()
{
    AbsoluteUnit& absUnit = *getAbsoluteUnit().get();
    ///
    /// Some other code
    ///
}
```

My question is: In Example2, when does the `unique_ptr` go out of scope?

In Example1 I am storing the `unique_ptr` in a local variable, so I would expect it to go out of scope when the function exits. But in Example2, I am not creating a local variable for it, so what happens to the `unique_ptr` after that line executes? Is it still scoped to the function, or does it immediately go out of scope?

Comment: By the way, you should remove the `std::move` on the return. The expression `std::unique_ptr(...)` is already a pr-value. Adding `std::move` will prevent copy elision and will make your code slower. A good compiler should warn against this.'

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was actually seeing a performance issue with this code, so that might be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` member function returns the pointer to the `AbsoluteUnit` object managed by the `std::unique_ptr<AbsoluteUnit>` that `getAbsoluteUnit()` returns.

That managed `AbsoluteUnit` object is then bound to the reference `absUnit`:

```
AbsoluteUnit& absUnit = *getAbsoluteUnit().get();
```

However, the `std::unique_ptr` ceases to exist just after this statement above, and therefore so does the managed `AbsoluteUnit` object. So, `absUnit` becomes a *dangling reference*.

---

If you want to avoid working with the pointer syntax, you could write instead:

```
const std::unique_ptr<AbsoluteUnit> ptr = getAbsoluteUnit();
AbsoluteUnit& obj = *ptr;
// ... use obj instead of ptr
```

or even more concise with `auto`:

```
const auto ptr = getAbsoluteUnit();
auto& obj = *ptr;
// ... use obj instead of ptr
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking would happen. Example1 is what I was thinking would be required, but the unit testing I did with Example2 passed (which doesn't mean that much in this case).